# How to control the speed of a SVG line animation with CSS

Tags: css, animation, svg, colors, css-animations

Sorry for the bad title, not sure how to explain it. I started messing around with SVG and animation CSS cause it's really cool, and I ran into a issue that I can't seem to get over. Here is the CSS I'm using:

```
 #Line {
    -webkit-animation: line-animation alternate 4s infinite;
 }      
 @-webkit-keyframes line-animation { 
        0%      {stroke-dasharray: 37%,112%;}
        100%    {stroke-dasharray: 1%,54%;stroke-dashoffset: 74%;}
 }
```

Codepen of what I've got so far (CHROME ONLY): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYvmEL

It starts out with 3 small lines, and slowly morphs into 1 lone line. When the long line stops, it slowly morphs back into 3 small lines but when it alternates direction, its super fast. How do I control the speed when it alternates back to be slower?

Here is a low quality Gif of what I'm trying to accomplish: https://gyazo.com/575f816bd9ac090f1e58f039a05ee07a

Looking at the outer line, you can see how the line smoothly creeps up to the end, and slowly morphs back.

If this made zero sense, please let me know so I can re-write it lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use three tween points in your `keyframes` declaration, and remove the `alternate` keyword.  The non-`alternate` version of your original keyframes declaration would be:

```
@-webkit-keyframes line-animation { 
    0%     { -- start state -- }
    50%    { -- end state -- }
    100%   { -- start state -- }
}
```

Now that you've done that, you should be able control the relative pace of the forward and reverse directions by changing the time position of the middle keyframe.  So to make the reverse direction longer than the forward direction, reduce the 50% value.

```
@-webkit-keyframes line-animation { 
    0%     { -- start state -- }
    30%    { -- end state -- }
    100%   { -- start state -- }
}
```

Note you will also need to at least double your timing value (to `8s` or more) to maintain the same pace as the original.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. Here is the final version: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQybdP